# Como acessar um id dinâmico através de uma diretiva?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Problema: Preciso dentro de uma diretiva angularJs, acessar um id montado dinamicamente dentro de um ng-repeat, e com isso manipular a classe de um item específico.

Resumidamente, estou usando o exemplo accordion do bootstrap, e no meu painel tenho um ng-repeat que a cada 5 segundos atualiza o conteúdo do objeto que estou iterando.
O que preciso fazer é manter o estado do meu painel ( expandido / não expandido ) mesmo após  a recarga dos dados do objeto que estou iterando.

Para controlar o estado gostaria de acessar dentro da diretiva o id do item que foi clicado ( para fechar o painel por exemplo ) e mantê-lo nesse estado, mesmo após a recarga dos dados.

OBS.: Quando os dados do objeto são recarregados, o estado anterior do painel não é mantido, ou seja, se não estava expandido, ele retorna ao estado inicial, que é do painel expandido ( Isso ocorre porque a minha estou usando a classe é panel-collapse collapse **in** no trecho que inclui as linhas abaixo do meu painel.

Abaixo meu arquivo html

```
<body ng-controller="Controller">
<!-- Header principal, com o menu titulo e pequisa de pessoas -->
<div class="panel-group" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="local in objeto.locais">
    <div class="panel-heading" ng-model="collapseLocal" ng-init="collapseLocal = true" ng-click="controlaPainel(local.id)">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#local-{{local.id}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="local-{{x.id}}">
            {{local.nome}}
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="local-{{x.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" my-repeat-directive>
      <div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="pessoa in local.pessoas">
          {{pessoa.nome}} 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
angular.module('teste', []).directive('myRepeatDirective', function(){
    return{
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

            for(x in $scope.p){
                $('#local-' + $scope.p[x]).removeClass('panel-collapse collapse in').addClass('panel-collapse collapse');
            }
        }
    }; }).controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$interval',function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.p = [];
    $scope.objeto = [];
    carregaValores();
    var intervalo = $interval( function() {
        carregaValores();
    }, 5000);
    $scope.controlaPainel = function(localId){
        var x = $scope.p.indexOf(localId);

        if(x == -1){
            $scope.p.unshift(localId);
        }else{
            $scope.p.splice(x ,1);    
        }
    }
    function carregaValores(){
        $scope.objeto = {"locais" :[
            {"id":"1", "nome": "Local 1", "pessoas":[{"nome" : "Maria"},{"nome" : "Joao"},{"nome" : "Pedro"}]},
            {"id":"2", "nome": "Local 2", "pessoas":[{"nome" : "Joselito"},{"nome" : "Osvaldo"}]}, 
            {"id":"3", "nome": "Local 3", "pessoas":[{"nome" : "Serafina"}]} 
        ]};
    }; }]);
```

Alguém por favor, conhece alguma alternativa para tratar essa situação ?

Comment: Seria possível você colocar um exemplo básico do funcionamento no [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)? Facilitaria muito o teste.

Comment: Esse é o plunker com o exemplo acima. Por algum motivo que não identifiquei o efeito para expandir ou não, não está funcionando no plunker.. mas quando abro a página no browser funciona :(, enfim acho que não vai adiantar muito, mas aí vai:
http://plnkr.co/edit/RAI9d7Qpt4pBhBVLzK3j?p=preview

Comment: Agora está ok, era a ordem de import dos script's. Coloquei o import do jQuery primeiro e agora dá para testar.

Comment: Consegui resolver tratando no arquivo .js para sincronizar apenas o array de pessoas durante o intervalo.

Answer (score 1):

- Quando o usuário selecionar um item do *Accordion*, salve o Id no `$scope`:

  - View

    ```
    <div 
     class="panel-heading" 
     ng-click="selecionaId(local.id)">
    ```
  - Controller

    ```
    $scope.selecionaId = function(parm) {
        $scope.IdSelecionado = parm;
    }
    ```
- Aplique, nos elementos sob iteração via `ng-repeat`, as classes que definem o seu comportamento via comparação ternária. Exemplo:

  ```
  <div ng-style="($local.id == IdSelecionado ) ? 'height: auto;' : 'height:0px;'">
  ```